# How can I get users email (and additional data) from the rest API?

Tags: users, email, rest-api, endpoints

How can I get the email adress from the users by using the REST API?
I'm authenticating with nonce, and it seems to be working since I can do POST requests and change stuff. Do I have to add something to make it return all the user info?

This is my JS:

```
(function($) {

    var nonce       = WPsettings.nonce;
    var rest_url    = WPsettings.rest_url;

    $.ajax( {
        url: rest_url + 'users/',
        dataType: "json",
        beforeSend: function ( xhr ) {
            xhr.setRequestHeader( 'X-WP-Nonce', nonce );
        }
    } )
   .done( function ( response ) {
        console.log( response );
    } );

})(jQuery);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To add the user's email address in the REST API response, register an additional field to the `user` object and add the email address:

```
register_rest_field(
    'user',
    'user_email',
    [
        'get_callback' => static function (array $user): string {
            return get_userdata($user['id'])->user_email;
        },
    ]
);
```

Please note, however, that this is *strongly* discouraged because anyone can then see the email addresses if the code is running on a publicly accessible website.

Comment: Thanks, i will try it out! It's not a problem I think since this will be used on a intranet only accessible from a restricted IP adress.

Comment: Okay. So you can use this method to get email address from Rest API. Please don't forget to choose best answer :)

Comment: Great, I will accept your answer as soon as I have confirmed that it works! :)

Comment: anyone else having issues getting this to work for retrieving email? I keep getting null for $user['email']

Comment: Did you see the results on the `$user` by `var_dump($user)`?

Comment: @big_water, code snippet was updated to your suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

If you're having an issue getting the email using Mostafa's answer, I had better luck swapping out the email retrieval as such:

```
register_rest_field( 'user', 'user_email',
                        array(
                            'get_callback'    => function ( $user ) {
                                return get_userdata($user['id'])->user_email;
                            },
                            'update_callback' => null,
                            'schema'          => null,
                        )
                    );
```

Answer (score 0):

I think u can return current_user email,

```
register_rest_field( 'user', 'user_email',
    array(
        'get_callback'    => function ( $user ) {
            return wp_get_current_user()->user_email;
        },
        'update_callback' => null,
        'schema'          => null,
    )
);
```

Comment: I think that would put the email address of the user that you're authenticating to the REST API as on all returned user records. Which doesn't sound right to me.

Comment: No, It will return only the current user.. so If User A logged-in so the return data will be his email.

Comment: Which API are you calling to trigger this and just get the current user? The one in the question was /wp-json/wp/v2/users/ which will return all of the users, but with my email address in every record.

Comment: Its wp-json/wp/v2/users/me https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/reference/users/#definition-5